# does package installer has two modes to install the app?

Tags: android, package

i gave my app to my friends to testing.When they install the apk second time manually,the `package installer`ask `new`  or `all` .when user choose new ,the app will use the same old data.so my app is crashing.how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does package installer has two modes to install the app?

Not really. Fresh installs are handled somewhat different than upgrades, but I would not consider that to be "two modes".

> When they install the apk second time manually,the package installerask new or all .

That is something specific to their device. That is not from standard Android. On an upgrade of an app (higher `versionCode`), your data in internal storage is automatically retained.

> so my app is crashing.how to avoid this?

Fix the bugs in your app. [Examine the Java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to determine where you are going wrong.

Comment: is there any way to clear all app data before reinstalling again?

Comment: @Asthme: A user can either uninstall the app or click the "Clear Data" button for your app via the Settings app. As a developer, there is a way that you can find out via a broadcast `Intent` that you were updated and attempt to use that to clear your data.